# CodeSignal Challenge: Phone Call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The [challenge](https://codesignal.com/) is:

Some phone usage rate may be described as follows:

- first minute of a call costs min1 cents
- each minute from the 2nd up to 10th (inclusive) costs min2_10 cents
- each minute after 10th costs min11 cents.

You have s cents on your account before the call. What is the duration of the longest call (in minutes rounded down to the nearest integer) you can have?

My Code: (My Code is not passing 3 of the hidden tests)

```js
function phoneCall(min1, min2_10, min11, s) {
    
    //Declaring Variables
    let minutes = 0;
    let taken = 0;
    
    //Checks if there is atleast one minute to charge for
    if (s >= min1) {
        minutes = minutes + 1;
        s = s - min1;
        //Console Update
        console.log("Call Length: " + minutes + " mins" + " |" + " Cents Left: " + s + " ¢");
    }
    
    //Checks how many minutes it can call for in between 2 and 10
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (s > 1) {
            minutes = minutes + 1;
            s = s - min2_10;
            //Console Update
            console.log("Call Length: " + minutes + " mins" + " |" + " Cents Left: " + s + " ¢");
        } 
        
        
        //Checks if minutes equals 10 and then checks for how many minutes it can afford
        if (minutes === 10) {
            if (s >= 1) {
                minutes = minutes + Math.floor(s / min11);
                taken = taken + Math.floor(s / min11); 
                s = s - (taken * min11);
                //Console Update
                console.log("Call Length: " + minutes + " mins" + " |" + " Cents Left: " + s + " ¢");
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Returns the minutes
    return minutes;
}
```

Comment: This is way too broad for StackOverflow. Please debug your code and come back with specific problems.

Comment: What is your question?  What is it telling you is not working?  Where is this test hosted?  I don't know how to help you because I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Seems strange that your method takes 3 separate variables for min. Why doesn't it just take call duration, and s?

Comment: I can't tell you what is wrong because they are hidden test, and I do not know what is not working, so if you think I am being to broad it is not my fault.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Also your snippet does not actually do anything

Comment: Oh, if you do not enter the snippet in codesignal then the parameters in the function will not work in a normal text editor, you would have to call the function with some values for the 4 parameters

Answer (score 0):

Just found what was not working!

The if statement was written as "if (s > 1) {}" but that was not written correctly because it would not work for all types of inputs, so I changed it to "if (s >= min2_10) {}".

This is the code:

```js
function phoneCall(min1, min2_10, min11, s) {
    
    //Declaring Variables
    let minutes = 0;
    let taken = 0;
    
    //Checks if there is atleast one minute to charge for
    if (s >= min1) {
        minutes = minutes + 1;
        s = s - min1;
        //Console Update
        console.log("Call Length: " + minutes + " mins" + " |" + " Cents Left: " + s + " ¢");
    }
    
    //Checks how many minutes it can call for in between 2 and 10
    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (s >= min2_10) {
            minutes = minutes + 1;
            s = s - min2_10;
            //Console Update
            console.log("Call Length: " + minutes + " mins" + " |" + " Cents Left: " + s + " ¢");
        } 
        
        
        //Checks if minutes equals 10 and then checks for how many minutes it can afford
        if (minutes === 10) {
            if (s >= 1) {
                minutes = minutes + Math.floor(s / min11);
                taken = taken + Math.floor(s / min11); 
                s = s - (taken * min11);
                //Console Update
                console.log("Call Length: " + minutes + " mins" + " |" + " Cents Left: " + s + " ¢");
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Returns the minutes
    return minutes;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function phoneCall(min1, min2_10, min11, s) {

  let result = s - min1 - (min2_10 * 9);
  let minLeft = Math.floor(result / min11);
  //case if have upto min1 only
  if (min1 === s) return 1;
  //case if have cents upto 10min or less and above 1min
  if (result < 0) return 1 + Math.floor((s - min1) / min2_10);
  //case if have cents more than 10min 
  //1min+9min for min2 to 10 mins = 10min
  return 10 + minLeft;
}
```